# Database XPath Queries

Tags: xml, database, xpath

I was given this XML and asked to indicate how many elements the expression returns:

```
<a>
  <a>
    <a>1</a>
    <a>2</a>
  </a>
  <a>
    <a>3</a>
    <a>4</a>
  </a>
</a>
```

The XPath queries are:

```
i) //a[a/text()=3]/a

ii) //a[a/a/text()=3]/a/a

iii) //a[a/text()=2][a/text()=3]
```

And the answers given are i) 2, ii) 4, iii) 0

However, I was having some problem when trying to understand it. For i),

What I understand is firstly I check the predicate. //a means descendant or self so that means I am checking at //a/a/3. Since I got a 3 in the path stated,

```
<a>
  <a>
    <a>3</a>
    <a>4</a>
  </a>
</a>
```

so the predicate is true. Then, I execute the XPath queries which is //a/a which will return me 2 as this block:

```
<a>
    <a>3</a>
    <a>4</a>
</a>
```

contains 2  inside. Then for ii), first I check the predicate //a/a/a/3, same as above I got that path. Since predicate is returning true, so I will execute the XPath query such as //a/a/a. But shouldn't it return as 1 since I am looking at this:

```
<a>
  <a>
    <a>1</a>
  </a>
</a>
```

I am really confused on how to trace it and I am pretty sure my concept is wrong as the answer is wrong. Is there any simple way to do it or maybe some better examples?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to explain the first XPath as an example. Test your understanding after reading this answer, by applying what you just understood to the rest of the XPath.

- `//a` : find *all* `a` elements, anywhere in the document. Up to this point 7 elements would be returned.
- `[a/text()=3]` : filter the `a` elements found by the previous XPath to those having *child element `a` where one of the child text node equals `3`*. Up to this point only one element would be returned; *the parent* of `<a>3</a>`.
- `/a` : return child element `a` from `<a>3</a>` element found by the previous XPath. It means the entire XPath would return 2 elements, since there are two `a` elements that is child of *parent of `<a>3</a>`*.

**<kbd>[`Demo 1`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/lH27mLYcX)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<a>3</a>
<a>4</a>
```

---

**UPDATE :**

Just realized that you are confused with the 2nd XPath rather than the 1st. But your understanding about the first is also a bit off, so I expect the initial answer is still useful. Here is a brief explanation about the 2nd XPath :

- `//a` : find *all* `a` elements, anywhere in the document. Up to this point 7 elements would be returned.
- `[a/a/text()=3]` : The expression in predicate would match parent of `<a>3</a>`. So the entire XPath up to this point would match only one element; *the root element*.
- `/a/a` : from the root element found by the previous XPath, return all grand-child `a` elements. So the entire XPath returns 4 elements

**<kbd>[`Demo 2`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/aM66K1Y21)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! But just a quick check with you regarding the last question, so //a returns 7 elements. Then the first predicate basically find the one with text node equals to 2, in this case I am left with the parent of <a>2</a> only. Then, after that, I perform another predicate to find 3 but since I am left with the parent 2 only and 3 is in another parent, so I cannot find any and thus return 0? Am I in the right track?

Comment: @WhoamI there you go! That's how the last XPath works. Congrats!